# Why Type 'Pick<T, K> & Omit<T, K>' is not assignable to type 'T'?

Tags: typescript

I found a puzzling error, let's say I want to have a rather useless function which merges two complementing partials of an object:

```
function foo<T extends object, K extends keyof T>(a: Pick<T, K>, b: Omit<T, K>): T {
    return { ...a, ...b } // TS2322: Type 'Pick<T, K> & Omit<T, K>' is not assignable to type 'T'. 'Pick<T, K> & Omit<T, K>' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'object'.
}
```

I got the error above, while the code below obviously works:

```
interface Test {
    a: string,
    b: string
}

const a: Pick<Test, 'a'> = { a: 'a' }
const b: Omit<Test, 'a'> = { b: 'b' }

const t: Test = { ...a, ...b }
```

The error is trying to tell me that I can come up with a `T` and `K` where `Pick<T, K> & Omit<T, K>` is not `T`. Can somebody give me such an example (or any other explanation for the error above)?

Edit 1:

What's even stranger is that TS itself considers `T extends Pick<T, K> & Omit<T, K>` true:

```
function foo<T extends object, K extends keyof T>(a: Pick<T, K>, b: Omit<T, K>): T extends Pick<T, K> & Omit<T, K> ? T : any {
    const res: Pick<T, K> & Omit<T, K> = { ...a, ...b }
    return res // TS2322: Type 'Pick<T, K> & Omit<T, K>' is not assignable to type 'T extends Pick<T, K> & Omit<T, K> ? T : any'.
}
```

Edit 2:

Apparently `Pick<T, K> & Omit<T, K>` is a subset of `T`, so there must be a case possible where something exists in `T` which does not exists in `Pick<T, K> & Omit<T, K>`:

```
function foo<T, K extends keyof T>(x: Pick<T, K> & Omit<T, K>): T {
    return x // TS2322: Type 'Pick<T, K> & Omit<T, K>' is not assignable to type 'T'. 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'Pick<T, K> & Omit<T, K>'.
}

function bar<T, K extends keyof T>(x: T): Pick<T, K> & Omit<T, K> {
    return x // no issue
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is indeed a possibility for unsoundness here. Both `Pick` and `Omit` are implemented as [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) and their result may not contain all the characteristic of the source type.

Consider this:

```
interface Test {
    (arg: string): string
    a: string,
    b: string
}

const a: Pick<Test, 'a'> = { a: 'a' }
const b: Omit<Test, 'a'> = { b: 'b' }

const t: Test = { ...a, ...b }
//    ~ Type '{ b: string; a: string; }' provides no match 
//      for the signature '(arg: string): string'
```

I have given `Test` a call signature. Both `Pick<Test, 'a'>` and `Omit<Test, 'a'>` do not result in a type with a call signature, leading to a situation where `Pick<Test, 'a'> & Omit<Test, 'a'>` is not assignable to `Test`.

There is also another problem: The compiler is lacking the ability to properly analyze the result of operations like `Pick<T, K>` when `T` and `K` are generic types. The types `T` and `K` act more like placeholders. Their concrete type is not known until the function is called, so the compiler only has a limited understanding what intersecting `Pick<T, K>` with `Omit<T, K>` would mean. You can see a discussion about a similar problem here at [#28884](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28884).

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5mQbwFDKHIAUcUA5gFzJZSjkCU1t9BRczYdI5ANG4QBGnbuTwBfPHgQB7EFmQdkABWAIA1gB50WXsgDkcfQD5kAXlyLqh-ckmz52YcgDyAW2BhtmMHpumLHGRnfUFbSWk5BTBqHWxA5AA6ZLg9ZMTBOzwAemyiZAA9AH40AE8ABxR9IOcWHgBuKxouekbxW3KoGQA3YAATTGQQGWQ3ODAEAAtkGBkoZDBJlAxgchBxgFcoKtIKEXomZtF9IA)